# How does discord.ext.commands work in Cog's?

Tags: discord.py

```
import discord
import os
import random
import time


from discord.ext import commands
```

These are my imports.

```
@bot.command()
async def online(ctx):
  response = ""

  guild = guild_get(ctx)
  
  for i in guild.members:
    if not i.bot:
      if i.status == discord.Status.offline:
        """ """
      else:
        response += i.mention
        response += ", "
  if len(response) > 0:
    await ctx.channel.send("||" + response + "||")
  else:
    await ctx.channel.send("No members are online.")
```

This code does work. ^^^

```
@commands.has_any_role("RoleName1","RoleName2","RoleName3")
@bot.command()
async def online(ctx):
  response = ""

  guild = guild_get(ctx)
  
  for i in guild.members:
    if not i.bot:
      if i.status == discord.Status.offline:
        """ """
      else:
        response += i.mention
        response += ", "
  if len(response) > 0:
    await ctx.channel.send("||" + response + "||")
  else:
    await ctx.channel.send("No members are online.")
```

This code doesn't ^^^

When i print every member it goes over in that loop, it only prints itself. It doesn't see any other member in the guild.

```
def guild_get(ctx):
  for guild in bot.guilds:
    if guild.id == ctx.guild.id:
      break
  return guild
```

Btw this is my guild_get() function.

Comment: Why do you need `guild_get`??! you can use `ctx.guild`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `members` intent in order for your bot to see other members/users.

```py
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="whatever", intents=intents)
# now your bot can see guild members.
```

---

### NOTE

Make sure to enable intents in your [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

[Click here](https://mee6.xyz/tutorials/how-to-enable-intents-on-your-custom-bot) to see a tutorial on **How to enable intents on your custom bot.**

Read more about **intents**:

- [`discord.py Privileged Intents`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents)
- [`Discord Gateway Intents`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents)